# How to add row to a DataGridView in C# when data-bound through LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datagridview

I have so far found in this site answers related to my questions but none seems to satisfy what I want to achieve. This is somehow a little different because of my approach to querying and updating database which uses LINQ to SQL Classes.

I already have this code:

```
public partial class FormControlDealerCodes : Form
{
    private DealerCodesDataContext dcdc = new DealerCodesDataContext();

    public FormControlDealerCodes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dealer_CodeDataGridView.DataSource = dcdc.Dealer_Codes;
    }
```

I understand that I can no longer use the following code since my [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netcore-3.1) control is data-bound:

```
    private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dealer_CodeDataGridView.Rows.Add();
    }
```

I've tried the following code:

```
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dealer_CodeDataGridView.DataSource;
        dt.NewRow();
```

but I'm drawn to a different error (*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table... to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.*)

I'm a newbie C# programming. Any generous one who could help me achieve what I want here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your LINQ source defined ?

Comment: I suppose to paste here the auto-generated class for DealerCodesDataContext but it's not possible. I think the LINQ source you wanted to see is

Comment: [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="Sample")]
 public partial class DealerCodesDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext

Comment: which comes from the auto-generated class.

Comment: The class was auto-generated by dragging the Dealer_Codes table onto the Object Relational Designer.

Comment: and by dragging the Dealer_Codes table from Data Sources onto the form. I eventually removed the auto-generated BindingSource, BindingNavigator, and the ToolStrip controls because I'm opting to provide button controls separately. I'm not sure actually if I'm doing everything right. I opt to removed the ToolStrip to hopefully replace buttons there with the button controls that can be made larger.

Comment: I guess, with no immediate answers, ToolStrip is inevitable with the use of Object Relational Designer.

Comment: By the way, thanks to you Anonymous for your time and concern and of course to more of what you can share to help me gain more knowledge about C#.

Comment: Sorry I lack familiarity with the ORM this but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-insert-rows-into-the-database) should help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll check on it.